# Type json in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dynamic json, for example:

```
{
    "first": "aaa",
    "second": "bbb",
    "other": "ttt"
}
```

And I created interface for this:

```
interface IResult {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

I have two components:

```
function FirstComponent() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState<IResult>();

    useEffect(() => {
       setResult(some action);
    })

    return {
        <SecondComponent result={result}>
    }
}


function SecondComponent(result: IResult) {}
```

But this return me error:

> Type "IResult" is not assignable to type 'string'.

in line: `<SecondComponent result={result}>`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post the actual error message so we can see where you're getting the error

Comment: `const (result, setResult)` shouldn't be `const [result, setResult]` you're not restructuring it right

Comment: @monim sorry, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass arguments to a component, it is taken as props.

By defining SecondComponent as `function SecondComponent(result: IResult) {}`, you are declaring types of props as `IResult` and not the type of props.result as `IResult`.

Modify your declaration as following:

```
interface IProps {
 result: IResult
}

function SecondComponent(props: IProps) {}
```